# How to keep Html element Hidden until Ajax post Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Form created using bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Post" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Age">Age:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="target" class="hidden" style="color:red;">Hi msg</label>    
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="press">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

The form has label in the latter which displays a text ( Hi msg). i want it to
be hidden initially and then become visible after my POST request is Successful,
my ajax call looks like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#press").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Post",
      success: function() {
        $("#target").removeClass("hidden");
      }
    }); 
  });
});
```

This is Basically trying to remove the Hidden class from the label after 
the post request is Successful. what am i doing wrong ? The problem is it becomes visible only for a couple of seconds until it turns hidden again.

Comment: Well, you didn't show your actual CSS `.hidden` class, but assuming it's `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0`, this looks correct.

Comment: Hi scott , am basically using Bootrap's native hidden property, i dont have a custom style for hidden.

Comment: You aren't preventing the default action of the button click which is to submit the form.

Comment: Hi charlietfl , can you please elaborate, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong with the Bootstrap class `hidden`. Try to replace this class with `d-none`.

Here is an example:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/RezaScript/tfe8mnoq/)

**Edit:**
To check if your post request was successful, here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#press").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Post",
      success: function(data) {
        if (data === 'true') {
            $("#target").removeClass("d-none");
        }        
      }
    }); 
  });
});
```

In this case, if the URL "*${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Post*" returns the string **true**, the class `d-none` will be removed.

Comment: Hi Reza your solution works , but my requirement is that it works if and only if the ajax post request is Successful.

Comment: Thanks alot for the Support Reza. the actual problem was the Bootrap button tag, i changed it to a div and my original code worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try just call the show() method. Usually the "hidden" class only set the display property in css.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#press").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Post",
      success: function() {
        $("#target").show();
      }
    }); 
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks Guma, the actual problem was the default bootrap button tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
I Actually Figured out the answer. the problem was the <button> tag which keeps on calling other Styles related to the button causing a reload effect at the Post Request. i changed the <button> tag to a <div>.

Basically From this;
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="press"> Submit </button>

To this;
<div type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="press"> Submit </div>

then my original code worked fine.
```